# Centered Menu Dropdowns in Purecss Framework

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu, pure-css

This is my current menu copied from [Purecss documentation](https://purecss.io/menus/) which [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/tnb07uj5/):

```
<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
<ul class="pure-menu-list">
    <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
        <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Contact</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-children">
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Email</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Twitter</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tumblr Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying now is to center the dropdown / submenu items under the parent menu (In this case `Contact`). I'm looking for a solution which works no matter of the parent menu length. Please note that I'm refering to the position of `pure-menu-children` class under the parent and not `text-align` of submenu items. I've already tried this with no luck:

```
.pure-menu-horizontal ul.pure-menu-children {
  left: -50%;
}
```

Hopefully it's clear and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what's 2 downvotes for without any comments? I thought the question might be helpful for those using Purecss too. Also I've already checked Stack Overflow for the answer with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I wanted after checking [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/y4vDC/). A width was needed to be set for the submenu:

```
.pure-menu-horizontal ul.pure-menu-children {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vemcz4k1/).